# How do I export any function that returns SYS_REFCURSOR to CSV or Excel or at least to any output where I can select, copy, and paste it somewhere

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Say I have the following:

```
function fn_myfunction ( param1 varchar2 ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
```

I just need a tool (free) or code snippet where I can simply insert select `fn_myfunction( param1 ... ) from dual` and give me all the result to CSV or Excel or any output where I can at least select, copy, and paste it somewhere without needing anything else.

I **don't** need a tool or code snippet that will **need me to specify what the columns** will be in that `SYS_REFCURSOR` because there are lots of them and I don't want to do that for all functions and new functions I'll encounter. I just need something that renders everything that sys_refcursor contains.

Alternatively:

Toad actually shows the result in a grid by double clicking on the first row after you fire your query. But the problem is that it doesn't allow me to select rows from it so I could copy and paste it somewhere useful. If you know how to copy from it, that too will serve as an answer to this question. I'm using Toad 10.1.1.8.

Comment: You may need to use **PLSQL Developer**. Right-click on the function, click on the *test*. Open test window, after doing that you will be able to open the result `sys_refcursor`, and then export it to *Exce*l, *csv*, *sql*, and so on.

Comment: Too bad, we don't have that. :(

Comment: I have have though, aside from Toad, is Oracle SQL Developer. It doesn't help either.

Comment: Just try **PLSQL Developer**.

Comment: @Stepan, I need something I can use for long term

Comment: Have a look at this list: [5 different ways to test Oracle Ref Cursor results](https://sqlandplsql.com/2013/04/30/5-different-ways-to-test-oracle-ref-cursor-results/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around Oracle SQL Developer, I found that it can be done by:

1. fire query from oracle sql developer
2. Double click on the first row. It should turn grey or something
3. Scroll to the far right and click on the "pen" icon
4. It should show you a popup dialogue box containing all the rows
5. Select all the recorcds you wish to copy

Cons:
Doesn't allow you to copy the headers.

If anyone could post better answer than this, I'd gladly accept it as an answer.